# how to wrap a single tab width in TabLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-tablayout

[image: custom tab]

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout

TabLayout provides a horizontal layout to display tabs.

Population of the tabs to display is done through TabLayout.Tab instances. You create tabs via newTab().

How to wrap a single tab in the android tab layout, as shown in the above screenshot.

I had given a solution also. If anyone has any better answer than this please share here.

Answer (score 3):

creating a simple activity XML having TabLayout => activity_tab_demo.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#27C7A1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

creating a custom single tab => tab1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Creating activity TabDemoActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.carowlers.R;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class TabDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_demo);
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        // making custom first tab
        TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.newTab();
        tab1.setCustomView(R.layout.tab1);

        //setting in tablayout
        tabLayout.addTab(tab1);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Chats"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Stories"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Calls"));
        wrapFirstTab(tabLayout);


    }

    public void wrapFirstTab(TabLayout tabLayout) {
        View tabStrip = tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        if (tabStrip instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup tabStripGroup = (ViewGroup) tabStrip;
            View tabView = tabStripGroup.getChildAt(0); // 0th position tab i.e 1st tab
            tabView.setMinimumWidth(0);
            tabView.setPadding(0, tabView.getPaddingTop(), 0, tabView.getPaddingBottom());
            tabView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            tabLayout.requestLayout();
        }
    }

}
```